# random number of " * " in a row in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, python-3.9

I want to generate a random number of " * " smaller than 21 and larger than 0 in a row for 100 times, in python

I tried to write:

```
import random 
for x in range(100): 
    a = random.randint(1, 20) 
    for y in a: 
        print("*")
```

Can someone help me?
I am beginner in programming

Comment: Get into an interactive python session and see what happens when you write a line like `5 * '*'`.

Answer (score 3):

You can multiply a string like `'a'*5 = 'aaaaa'`

```py
import random 
for x in range(100): 
    #a = random.randint(1, 20)
    #print('*'*a)
    print('*'*random.randint(1, 20))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a single line like this:

```
from random import randint
print(*( "*"*randint(1,20) for _ in range(100) ),sep="\n")
```

The print function can accept multiple value and separate them with a string supplied in its `sep=` parameter (here `"\n"` for a new line).

You can generate 100 strings with a comprehension `(... for _ in range(100))` where each string is a random repetition of the `"*"` character (repeated by multiplying the single character by a random number).

This comprehension can be converted to individual parameters for the print function using unpacking `*(...)`

Answer (score 0):

**Is this ok ? I just Added range in the second for loop and end = "\n" in first loop and end = "" in inner loop**

```
import random 
for x in range(100): 
    a = random.randint(1, 20) 
    for y in range (a) : 
        print("*",end = "")
    print(end = "\n")
```